# Get updated copy of environment variable in java

Tags: java, environment-variables

I want to get latest/updated copy on environment variable using java.

Java is not returning latest copy if someone changed particular environment variable after running a programme.

please use below sample code to test the scenario.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test extends Thread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        while (true) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, System.getenv("A"));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Tried ProcessBuilder also

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("echo %A%");
System.out.println(processBuilder.environment().get("A"));
```

Comment: How did you change the environment? Just exporting a variable after running a program doesn't change that program's environment.

Comment: For windows  i am using System Property dialog.

Answer (score 1):

The environment variables are set when the JVM starts and will not change.

That is generally true for all Windows programs. E.g. start a Command Prompt, change an environment variable through the Windows Control Panel, and the Command Prompt will *not* see the changed value.

Only Command Prompts opened *after* the change will see the change.

Comment: I know about "Command Prompt", is there any way to achieve my requirement ?

Comment: @yogeshprajapati Not really. Environmental variables just behave like that, both on Windows and on Linux/Unix. When a new program is started, a snapshot of all variables is made and their values are not "attached" to the original shell/whatever run the program any more. You should look for a different way of sending the information you need to transport between the shell and your application.

Comment: I agree with @MichałKosmulski. Programs should generally use a configuration file (XML, Properties, ...), with perhaps a Java System Property or an Environment Variable to specify the *location* of the configuration file. If you want changes to the configuration file to be applied to an already running program, it's up to you to code the program to monitor the configuration file for changes.